# Local Login Hyperledger Composer

Tags: rest, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

there are no guides available but it should be theoretically possible to set up a local login for the hyperledger REST server...

Has someone been able to implement a local one?, or rather can someone recommend a mechanisam other than OAuth that he can recommend for the implementation?

Until now, I spend pretty much unsuccefully to implement it but I don't know why it is not working...

Kind Regards
Cheerio!

Answer (score 0):

did you mean 'authenticate' locally...for the REST server ?  You could always use passport-ldapauth from http://www.passportjs.org/packages/

If you mean building a multi-user application for users to login/authenticate then connect to a business network as REST client to consume REST APIs/interact with a business network on the blockchain - see these useful resources/guides:

[Building a real time application USing composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791061/building-a-real-time-application-using-composer)

https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc