# Hyperledger Composer & Ionic Cordova mobile application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In my business network, the admin owns the back office and each participant can interact with the blockchain through his mobile app.

Does anyone know how to access a *Hyperledger* *Composer* blockchain business network through a *Ionic* *Cordova* mobile app ?
Each participant has to run a `composer-rest-server`? How do I set up the connection in the Ionic app ?

Please show me an exemple if you have one.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

these resources should help you understand how to interact with a Composer-based blockchain business network. You would set up application participants with business network cards - they are 'users'  of the business network on the blockchain. This will allow them, as application users to (ultimately) interact with the business network through a set of secured REST endpoints from which calls to the REST server (highly available etc) are made.

[Hyperledger Composer Web application user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893410/hyperledger-composer-web-application-user-authentication/48906459#48906459)

https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc

[Building a real time application USing composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791061/building-a-real-time-application-using-composer/47793332#47793332)

https://www.joshmorony.com/basic-security-for-ionic-cordova-applications/

Comment: Thanks Paul. I’ve understood that each participant needs an identity and a connection card to interact with the business network. But I still have difficulty with the rest server process. Considering a back office running on my laptop, a composer-rest-server is running on port 3000 and I’m connected as admin. I create a new participant user1, with its associated identity and card. But then from my mobile phone app, I want to connect to the business network as user1. How to do that ? By running a rest-server on my mobile or by connecting on the rest-server of my laptop ? Many thanks. Arnaud

Comment: No, your mobile app client authenticates via app auth provider ; he gets a token ; the APP connects with a business network card and so can interact (eg. through REST API calls, as a client, passing the token each time) with the business network through APIs, like you would, if you were just using any browser app to connect and use the API endpoints.